# "IndexError: Too many levels" when running Featuretools dfs after upgrade

Tags: featuretools

Featuretools' `dfs()` method fails to run on my entity set after upgrading from v0.1.21 to v0.2.x and v0.3.0.

The error is raised when the Pandas backend tries to calculate the aggregate features `_calculate_agg_features()`. In particular:

```
--> 442 to_merge.reset_index(1, drop=True, inplace=True)
...
IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2
```

This is working fine in v0.1.x and the entity set hasn't changed after the upgrade. The entity set is composed of 7 entities and 6 relationships. Each entity (dataframe) is added via `entity_from_dataframe`.

Comment: Given this is more of potential bug, can you post this as an issue on github? https://github.com/Featuretools/featuretools/issues. When you do, please share runnable code that can reproduce this error and report the version numbers of installed python libraries by running `pip freeze`. Without that we won't be able to help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @MaxKanter, I've opened [#252](https://github.com/Featuretools/featuretools/issues/252)

Comment: thanks. replied with a potential fix there

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

where `df` is the name of dataframe. This may solve this problem.